# Find the total height of the cats if they are standing on top of one another

Tags: javascript

> The Cat In The Hat has cat A under his hat, cat A has cat B under his
> hat and so on until Z.
>
> The Cat In The Hat is 2,000,000 cat units tall.
>
> Each cat is 2.5 times bigger than the cat underneath their hat.
>
> Find the total height of the cats if they are standing on top of one
> another.
>
> Counting starts from the Cat In The Hat
>
> n = the number of cats
>
> fix to 3 decimal places.

I tried to solve this by

```js
function height(n) {
  const a = 2.5;
  const repetition = 2000000;
  let result = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < repetition; i++) {
    result += n * a;
  }

  return result.toFixed(3);
}
```

I'm assuming its not working because the numbers are really big and it may be interfering with the result. At 1st I did expect this to work but it did not.

This is a problem on *Code Wars* that I'm having a hard time solving.

Comment: the anawer is max 1, if they are not kittens or rusty-spotted cats. Rusty-spotted max 2, kittens... well... would say 5, but maybe it's worth to write an algorytm only for that

Comment: And where are you stuck?

Comment: First of all - _which_ problem are you actually trying to solve here now? _"How many cats are in the hat?"_ and _"Find the total height of the cats if they are standing on top of one another."_ (with a _given_ number of cats) are two totally different things, are they not?

Comment: cbroe i fixed it sorry one of my 1st questions

Answer (score 0):

My understanding that the problem you're facing stems from the way you're calculating the height. The loop in your code is repeating the addition of n * a for repetition number of times. However, this approach doesn't correctly account for the fact that each subsequent cat is 2.5 times bigger than the previous one.

To solve this problem, you can use a recursive function that calculates the height by multiplying the height of the previous cat by 2.5 and adding it to the height of the current cat.

Here's an example implementation

```
function height(n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  const previousCatHeight = height(n - 1);
  const currentCatHeight = previousCatHeight * 2.5;
  return previousCatHeight + currentCatHeight;
}

const totalHeight = height(26); // Calculate height for 26 cats (from A to Z)
console.log(totalHeight.toFixed(3)); // Output: 11718750.000
```

In this code, the `height` function recursively calculates the height of each cat by multiplying the height of the previous cat by 2.5 and adding it to the current cat's height. The base case `if (n === 0)` stops the recursion when it reaches the Cat in the Hat.

Using this approach, the total height of the cats, starting from the Cat in the Hat and going through 26 cats (A to Z), is approximately 11,718,750.000 units when rounded to 3 decimal places.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You want `return 1;` for base case. (or 2 million as OP said)

Answer (score 0):

I think you really have to read the question closely here,.

The original cat is 2_000_000 units high, so we start at that.

Each cat under each cat hat is 2.5 times smaller,.  `Each cat is 2.5 times bigger than the cat underneath their hat.` note it says cat underneath, not on top.  So you divide by 2.5, not multiply.

And of course there are 27 cats, as their is a-z, plus the original cat in the hat.

So the code ->

```js
let totalHeight = 0;
let catHeight = 2_000_000;  //original cat size
for (let l = 0; l <= 26; l ++) {  
  //start at 0, as we include the original cat in the hat
  totalHeight += catHeight; //add to total height
  catHeight /= 2.5; //next cat is 2.5 times smaller
}
  
console.log(totalHeight.toFixed(3));
```

Comment: "*[U]nderneath a cat's hat*" means to stand on its top, no?

Comment: @InSync   This is the bit were I said you have to read it carefully. :)    `Each cat is 2.5 times bigger`  <--  So we have a `cat` that is 2.5 bigger than -> `the cat underneath their hat.`    So the cat has a hat, with a cat underneath it, and `this` cat is 2.5 times bigger.  IOW: Each cat under each cat's hat is 2.5 times smaller than the cat's hat it was underneath..  :)

Comment: ...which means the smaller stands on the top of the bigger; exactly what I said.

Comment: @InSync  And is exactly what I'm saying..  And is why I divide by 2.5, and not multiple by 2.5.  Was there some other point you was making?.   Or was you just clarifying what I was saying..?

Comment: No, just clarifying. Thanks for the confirmation.